# How to make ClusterManager recognize default Marker?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am writing a simple Google Maps app for Android.

There is [marker clusterer utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering?hl=uk) which has to provide markers grouping. By default, it does work only with `ClusterItem`, not `Marker`.

What do I have to override there to make it work as wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you cannot. It is part of the Android Maps Utils API and you would have to modify the library for your needs.

If you want to use something less conflicting with your current map-related code, you may want to try [Android Maps Extensions](https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions) library. Disclosure: I created this library.

Comment: Your library worked like a charm! Now it does display simple markers instead of circles with number of markers. How can I make it display like in JavaScript API?

Comment: [The demo app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.mg6.android.maps.extensions.demo) has a `ClusterOptionsProvider` implementation that mimics javascript's lib look and feel. Just copy that to your project. If you don't use any `ClusterOptionsProvider`, default one should be used and it would not show "simple markers".